# Generate benchmark table

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, prettytable

I have generated benchmarks for comparing two approaches taken for scaling video files using ffmpeg tool.

The benchmarks are logged in this format :

```
x.mp4 Output_Resolution : 10 p

Parameter1 : a

Method : A

real    0m5.788s
user    0m16.112s
sys     0m0.313s

Method : B, ParameterB1 : b11

ParameterB2 : b21

real    0m6.637s
user    0m16.618s
sys     0m0.720s

ParameterB2 : b22

real    0m5.486s
user    0m17.570s
sys     0m0.568s

ParameterB2 : b23

real    0m5.232s
user    0m18.212s
sys     0m0.718s

Method : B, ParameterB1 : b12

ParameterB2 : b21

real    0m6.398s
user    0m16.790s
sys     0m0.528s

ParameterB2 : b22

real    0m5.449s
user    0m17.229s
sys     0m0.533s

ParameterB2 : b23

real    0m5.275s
user    0m18.411s
sys     0m0.522s

##################################################################################################################

Parameter1 : b

Method : A

real    0m5.927s
user    0m16.451s
sys     0m0.308s

Method : B, ParameterB1 : b11

ParameterB2 : b21

real    0m6.685s
user    0m17.044s
sys     0m0.597s

ParameterB2 : b22

real    0m5.942s
user    0m18.971s
sys     0m0.804s

ParameterB2 : b23

real    0m6.119s
user    0m20.869s
sys     0m0.792s

.
.
.
```

There are two methods (A and B). Method A and B share Parameter1 which can take values `a,b,c...`.
Method B has other parameters B1 and B2. ParameterB1 and ParameterB2 take values `b11,b12,b13...` and `b21,b22,b23...` respectively. A line separator (which consists of multiple `#`) is used to separate the measurements for different values of Parameter1.

I would like to view the benchmarks in tabular format.

```
+--------+---------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| Method |                                       | Parameter1 (a) | Parameter1 (b) | Parameter1 (c) |
+--------+---------------------------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|    A   |                   NA                  | 4.03s          | 3.23s          | 1.4s           |
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|    B   | ParameterB1 (b11) | ParameterB2 (b21) | .              |                |                |
|        |                   +-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|        |                   | ParameterB2 (b22) | .              |                |                |
|        |                   +-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|        |                   | ParameterB2 (b23) | .              |                |                |
|        +-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|        | ParameterB1 (b12) | ParameterB2 (b21) | .              |                |                |
|        |                   +-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|        |                   | ParameterB2 (b22) | .              |                |                |
|        |                   +-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|        |                   | ParameterB2 (b23) | .              |                |                |
|        +-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|        | ParameterB1 (b12) | ParameterB2 (b21) | .              |                |                |
|        |                   +-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|        |                   | ParameterB2 (b22) | .              |                |                |
|        |                   +-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|        |                   | ParameterB2 (b23) | .              |                |                |
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

The cell values consists of the real time values in seconds (`real 0m6.119s`).

How can I generate such a table using python?

---

I have written a "not-so-efficient" python script with the help from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60964181/10155936) from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60861191/10155936) I asked a few months ago.

```
import pprint

def gettime(x):
    m,s = map(float,x[:-1].split('m'))
    return 60 * m + s

with open("log") as fp:
    lines = fp.read().splitlines()

idx = 0
A = {}
B = {}

while idx < len(lines):
    if "Parameter1" in lines[idx]:
        Parameter1 = lines[idx].split(' ')[-1]
        temp1 = {}
        idx += 2
        if "A" in lines[idx]:
            idx += 2
            A[Parameter1] = gettime(lines[idx].split('\t')[-1])
            while idx < len(lines):
                if "B" in lines[idx]:
                    ParameterB1 = lines[idx].split(' ')[-1]
                    temp2 = {}
                    idx += 1
                    while idx < len(lines):
                        if "ParameterB2" in lines[idx]:
                            ParameterB2 = lines[idx].split(' ')[-1]
                            idx += 2
                            temp2[ParameterB2] = gettime(lines[idx].split('\t')[-1])
                        elif "#" in lines[idx] or "B" in lines[idx]:
                            break
                        idx += 1
                    temp1[ParameterB1] = temp2
                elif "#" in lines[idx]:
                    B[Parameter1] = temp1
                    break
                else:
                    idx += 1
    else:
        idx += 1
        
print("A")
print(A)

pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(sort_dicts = False, depth = 4)
print("B")
pp.pprint(B)
```

This script parses the log and stores the measurements obtained for respective methods and parameters in a dictionary.

Example output from the script :

```
A
{'a': 4.03, 'b': 3.23, 'c': 1.4}
B
{'a': {'b21': {'b11': 0.0, 'b12': 0.0, 'b13': 0.0},
       'b22': {'b11': 0.0, 'b12': 0.0, 'b13': 0.0},
       'b23': {'b11': 0.0, 'b12': 0.0, 'b13': 0.0}},
 'b': {'b21': {'b11': 0.0, 'b12': 0.0, 'b13': 0.0},
       'b22': {'b11': 0.0, 'b12': 0.0, 'b13': 0.0},
       'b23': {'b11': 0.0, 'b12': 0.0, 'b13': 0.0}},
 'c': {'b21': {'b11': 0.0, 'b12': 0.0, 'b13': 0.0},
       'b22': {'b11': 0.0, 'b12': 0.0, 'b13': 0.0},
       'b23': {'b11': 0.0, 'b12': 0.0, 'b13': 0.0}}}
```

How can I print this in tabular format as described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extended the python script (in the question) further to represent the the data stored in the dictionaries in tabular format using pretty table.

```
import pprint
import io
from prettytable import PrettyTable 
# install PTable package

def gettime(x):
    m,s = map(float,x[:-1].split('m'))
    return 60 * m + s

with open("log") as fp:
    lines = fp.read().splitlines()

idx = 0
A = {}
B = {}
Parameter1_list = []
ParameterB1_list = []
ParameterB2_list = []

while idx < len(lines):
    if "Parameter1" in lines[idx]:
        Parameter1 = lines[idx].split(' ')[-1]
        Parameter1_list.append(Parameter1)
        temp1 = {}
        idx += 2
        if "A" in lines[idx]:
            idx += 2
            A[Parameter1] = gettime(lines[idx].split('\t')[-1])
            while idx < len(lines):
                if "B" in lines[idx]:
                    ParameterB1 = lines[idx].split(' ')[-1]
                    ParameterB1_list.append(ParameterB1)
                    temp2 = {}
                    idx += 1
                    while idx < len(lines):
                        if "ParameterB2" in lines[idx]:
                            ParameterB2 = lines[idx].split(' ')[-1]
                            ParameterB2_list.append(ParameterB2)
                            idx += 2
                            temp2[ParameterB2] = gettime(lines[idx].split('\t')[-1])
                        elif "#" in lines[idx] or "B" in lines[idx]:
                            break
                        idx += 1
                    temp1[ParameterB1] = temp2
                elif "#" in lines[idx]:
                    B[Parameter1] = temp1
                    break
                else:
                    idx += 1
    elif ".mp4" in lines[idx]:
        title = lines[idx]
        idx += 1
    else:
        idx += 1

#print("A")
#print(A)

#pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(sort_dicts=False,depth=4)
#print("B")
#pp.pprint(B)

Parameter1 = list(dict.fromkeys(Parameter1_list))
ParameterB1 = list(dict.fromkeys(ParameterB1_list))
ParameterB2 = list(dict.fromkeys(ParameterB2_list))

t1 = PrettyTable(['Method','ParameterB1','ParameterB2'])
t2 = PrettyTable(Parameter1)

t1.title = title
t2.title = "Parameter1"

t1.add_row(['A','NA','NA'])
t2.add_row(A.values())

for d in ParameterB1:
    for c in ParameterB2:
        values = []
        for e in Parameter1:
            values.append(B[e][d][c])
        t1.add_row(['B',d,c])
        t2.add_row(values)

o1 = io.StringIO(t1.get_string())
o2 = io.StringIO(t2.get_string())

with open(0,"w") as f1, open('result.txt',"w") as f2:
    for x,y in zip(o1,o2):
        f1.write(x.strip()[:-1] + y.strip() + "\n")
        f2.write(x.strip()[:-1] + y.strip() + "\n")
```

This writes the table to a file (`result.txt`) and stdout.

Output :

```
+------------------------------------+-------------------+
|   x.mp4  Output Resolution : 10p   |     Parameter1    |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------+------+-----+
| Method | ParameterB1 | ParameterB2 |  a   |  b   |  c  |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------+------+-----+
|   A    |      NA     |      NA     | 4.03 | 3.23 | 1.4 |
|   B    |     b11     |     b21     | 0.0  | 0.0  | 0.0 |
|   B    |     b11     |     b22     | 0.0  | 0.0  | 0.0 |
|   B    |     b11     |     b23     | 0.0  | 0.0  | 0.0 |
|   B    |     b12     |     b21     | 0.0  | 0.0  | 0.0 |
|   B    |     b12     |     b22     | 0.0  | 0.0  | 0.0 |
|   B    |     b12     |     b23     | 0.0  | 0.0  | 0.0 |
|   B    |     b13     |     b21     | 0.0  | 0.0  | 0.0 |
|   B    |     b13     |     b22     | 0.0  | 0.0  | 0.0 |
|   B    |     b13     |     b23     | 0.0  | 0.0  | 0.0 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------+------+-----+
```

This is the closest I could represent the data in tabular format that I have described in the question.